# AWS SDK for IOS from v1 to v2 about the "S3objectsummary"

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Here is a function of `progressbar`. In the `sdk v1` I can use "S3Objectsummary" to know the summary of the the file, but in the `sdk v2` i can not found the "S3Objectsummary".

Which one is the similar one in the v2? If any one can show an example that will be great.

Also, i have the same question with

```
S3GetObjectRequest/S3GetObjectResponse/S3PutObjectRequest/AmazonClientException
```

Code is in the `sdk ios v1`:

```
-(AmazonS3Client *)s3{
[self validateCredentials];
return s3;}

-(void)validateCredentials{
NSLog(@"validating credentials.");
if (s3 == nil) {
    [self clearCredentials];
    s3  = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
}
}

-(void)setProgressBar{
[delegate setProgressStatus:progPercent];
}

-(void)downloadPlists{
@try {
    NSArray *Plists = [[self s3] listObjectsInBucket:@"~~~~"];

    float numfile = 1;
    float totalfiles = [Plists count];

    for (S3ObjectSummary *file in Plists) {
        float percent = numfile/totalfiles;
        progPercent = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:percent];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setProgressBar) withObject:progPercent waitUntilDone:YES];
        numfile++;
        NSString *key = [file key];
        NSLog(@"key: %@", key);
        if ([key rangeOfString:@".plist"].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *plistFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Plists/%@",docDir, key];
            NSLog(@"plistFilePath: %@", plistFilePath);

            S3GetObjectRequest *plist = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:key withBucket:@"~~~~~"];
            S3GetObjectResponse *getObjectResponse = [[self s3] getObject:plist];

            NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData: getObjectResponse.body];

            NSString *courseFilePath = [plistFilePath substringToIndex:[plistFilePath rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location];
            bool testDirectoryCreated = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath: courseFilePath
                                                                 withIntermediateDirectories: YES 
                                                                                  attributes: nil 
                                                                                       error: NULL];
            if (!testDirectoryCreated)
                NSLog(@"error creating test directory.");

            if (![data2 writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:YES])
                NSLog(@"error writing to path.");
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"There was an error performing this operation. Please try again later. Error: %@", exception] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [failureAlert show];
}

}
```

I try to do the same thing in v2 in the code as follow, is the code right?

```
-(void)downloadPlists
```

{

```
    AWSS3 *s3 = [AWSS3 defaultS3];

    AWSS3ListObjectsRequest *listObjectReq=[AWSS3ListObjectsRequest new];
    listObjectReq.bucket=@"PLists";

    [[[s3 listObjects:listObjectReq] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        if(task.error){
            NSLog(@"the request failed. error %@",task.error);
        }
        if(task.result){
            AWSS3ListObjectsOutput *listObjectsOutput=task.result;
            NSArray *Plists = task.result;    //Is the result of task in listObjectOutput a NSArray?
            float numfile = 1;
            float totalfiles = [Plists count];
            for(AWSS3Object *file in listObjectsOutput.contents){
                float percent = numfile/totalfiles;
                progPercent = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:percent];
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setProgressBar) withObject:progPercent waitUntilDone:YES];
                numfile++;
                NSString *key = [file key];
                NSLog(@"key: %@", key);
                if ([key rangeOfString:@".plist"].location != NSNotFound) {
                    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

                    NSString *plistFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Plists/%@",docDir, key];
                    NSLog(@"plistFilePath: %@", plistFilePath);


                    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
                    AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest *downloadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new];
                    downloadRequest.bucket = @"PLists";
                    downloadRequest.key = key;
                    //downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"???"];  I'm not sure the path.  In sdk V1 there is no URL ?

                    [[transferManager download: downloadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                        if (task.error) {

                            UIAlertView *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!"
                                                                                   message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"There was an error performing this operation. Please try again later. Error: %@", task.error]
                                                                                  delegate:nil
                                                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                                                         otherButtonTitles: nil];
                            [failureAlert show];
                        }

                        if (task.result) {
                            AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput *downloadOutput = task.result;

                            NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithData: downloadOutput.body];

                            NSString *courseFilePath = [plistFilePath substringToIndex:[plistFilePath rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location];
                            bool testDirectoryCreated = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath: courseFilePath
                                                                                 withIntermediateDirectories: YES
                                                                                                  attributes: nil
                                                                                                       error: NULL];
                            if (!testDirectoryCreated)
                                NSLog(@"error creating test directory.");

                            if (![data2 writeToFile:plistFilePath atomically:YES])
                                NSLog(@"error writing to path.");

                        }
                        return nil;
                    }];

            }

        }
            return nil;
        }

        return nil;
    }] waitUntilFinished];   //In the integration test still use the "waitUntilFinisher".But in the "Working with BFTask" said the continueWithBolck won't execute until the previous asychronous call has already finished exceuting?
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`AWSS3Object` in v2 is equivalent to `S3ObjectSummary` in v1.

You are not invoking `- listObjects:`, so your v2 code snippet does not work. You should take a look at the [integration test](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSiOSSDKTests/AWSS3Tests.m#L218) as an example. Note that you should avoid calling `- waitUntilFinished` in your production app. See [Working with BFTask](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/bftask.html) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I hv been change the code "try...catch" with BFTask. I want to know if I use [s3 listObjects:listObjectReq]  "task.result" is what? A  a NSArray?  Or I should get the task.result and put it into a NSArray then use the count to get the totalfiles?  . In the AWSS3ListObjectsOutput Class Reference, I cannot found a Tasks to get the numbers of totalfiles.  And in the example of "integration test" use "[AWSS3Object *s3Object in listObjectsOutput.contents]" what's mean by contents ? The API donot hv a interpretation for this Task.

Comment: If you hv any example like [aws-sdk-ios-samples](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferManager-Sample/Objective-C/S3TransferManagerSample) is great.Thanks.